# Adding mutliple textview to expandablelistview in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have followed this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ to create an **ExpandableListView**.But i want to change the child view.For that my xml layout is

**text.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.projectguideapp.SettingActivity" >
      >


        <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                 android:paddingRight="12dp"   
                 android:paddingBottom="12dp"                 
                 android:orientation="vertical" >                    

                  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/descriptionborder">

                      <LinearLayout
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_weight="2" >

                         <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ele1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"                           
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center|"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>                                                          

                      </LinearLayout>

                      <View android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="#C0C0C0"/>

                      <LinearLayout
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="vertical" 
                          android:layout_weight="2.5" >

                          <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/edes1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"                           
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>                         

                      </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>                   
      </LinearLayout>
```

In the example link there is only one textview but i want two textview in the child view and display two different array's in the two textviews.

My **ExpandableListView** code of childview is

```
TextView Child = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ele1);
TextView Child1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edes1);       
Child.setText(childText);
Child1.setText(childText);
```

both textviews are displaying the same values of array in the above code.what changes has to be made two display different **arraylist** in the **textviews**.

Comment: Any suggestions for this

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you are giving the same text to both text views. So change the text given to the textviews

Change these lines

```
Child.setText(childText);
Child1.setText(childText);
```

to

```
Child.setText(childText);
Child1.setText(childText1);
```

childText1 is the text from the second array list with the same child position